# Is Laravel Horizon runtime per job or total throughput?

Tags: laravel, laravel-horizon

I have a question about Laravel Horizon throughput and runtime metrics.

If we are getting 1,000 jobs done at a point in time, and that throughput has a runtime of `0.045` seconds

Is that runtime 0.045 seconds **per job**, or the runtime to execute the 1,000 jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max throughput mean how many job are being processed in the time interval.

Comment: That's what I thought. Can anyone else confirm? Thanks!

Comment: see this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-horizon-max-runtime-and-max-throughput-meaning